# How can I avoid overlapping of multiple images, while pasting on one background image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, paste

I am pasting multiple images randomly on the custom white background image, but I cannot figure out how can I avoid images to overlap each other? What I want is that every time an image is pasted, it must not be on the same position as the previous image. So far, I wasn't able to find much on it.
Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
  for image_to_paste in os.listdir(path):

    image_to_paste = Image.open(os.path.join(path, image_to_paste))
    i_width, i_height = image_to_paste.size
    b_width, b_height = back_image.size
    img = random.randint(0, max(0, back_image.size[0]-image_to_paste.size[0])), \
        random.randint(0, max(0, back_image.size[1]-image_to_paste.size[1]))
    back_image.paste(image_to_paste, img)
    n += 1
    
    if n == 5:
        back_image.save(f'path to save output images\_{n}.jpg')
        back_image = Image.new('RGB', (1440, 900), (255, 255, 255, 255))
        n = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that pastes multiple images on a white background and avoids them to overlap. It generates random x and y coordinates for each image, and checks if the new image overlaps with any previous images before placing it. If it does overlap, new x and y coordinates are generated until it does not overlap.

```py
import random
from PIL import Image

def random_coordinates(width, height, existing_coordinates, image):
    """Generate random x, y coordinates within the given dimensions,
    making sure they do not overlap with any existing coordinates."""
    img_width, img_height = image.size
    x, y = random.randint(0, width-img_width), random.randint(0, height-img_height)
    while any(x <= x2+w and x+img_width >= x2 and y <= y2+h and y+img_height >= y2 for x2, y2, w, h in existing_coordinates):
        x, y = random.randint(0, width-img_width), random.randint(0, height-img_height)
    return (x, y, img_width, img_height)

def place_images(images, background_path):
    """Paste the given images onto the background, with or without overlap."""
    background = Image.new('RGB', (400, 400), (255, 255, 255))
    coordinates = []
    for image in images:
        x, y, w, h = random_coordinates(background.width, background.height, coordinates, image)
        coordinates.append((x, y, w, h))
        background.paste(image, (x, y))
    background.save(background_path)
    return background
```

You would use this function by calling `place_images(images, background_path)` where images is a list of PIL images and background_path is a string representing the path of the white background image.